# Get html source page of the user with facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the source page of the facebook user **after he logged in**, the login is with Facebook api, I'm using php language.

For example:

1. Some user login to my app named "FName LName"
2. So I want the source page of "view-source: https://www.facebook.com/FName.LName"

Let's say that I have a string variable to store the whole html content, How can I do that?

this `echo file_get_contents('https://www.facebook.com/FName.LName);` gives the login page, I need the source page of the profile page of the **same user that logged in to my app**.

I used [this toutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BcwbftTWGE) for php facebook graph api, my code looks like [this](https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/canvas-app-login-get-basic-info.php).

Is it possible? can you show me how step by step please? (with code)

Comment: Why do you need the source of the page? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve what you want. If you really want to get the source I suggest you check out PhantomJS. You can use that to log in to your facebook account and navigate to the user's page. But you'll soon find yourself trying to avoid the dreaded facebook captcha, which is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed by their Terms of Service or Platform Policy